# php lib memcached strange input value

Tags: c#, php, memcached

I am using php along with memcached.
Now I push the following two values into the cache:

```
[{"size":"8","0":"8","active":"1","1":"1"}]
[{"id":"1","URL":"http:\/\/myurl.com","status":"0"}]
```

I can set and retreive them in php without problem.
However, I also want to access this variable from C# (I then parse the JSON).
All went well for the first value, but I got weird results for the second! I didn't understand why, and I still don't. After getting the value directly from memcached from a telenet session, I got the following:

[weird output http://i55.tinypic.com/dwrn83.png](http://i55.tinypic.com/dwrn83.png)

I have no clue on why this happens? Someone said something about the php lib doing something with ASCII vs. unicode to me, but I don't know if this is true, nor do I know how to solve it.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to escape forward slashes. `"http://myurl.com"` is perfectly fine.

Comment: It seems that json_encode() in php escapes those slashes.

Comment: This is... weird. When I urlencode the url before json_encode()ing it, I get the following result from memcached: #®VÊLQ²R23WÒQ21B|ÌUcGU#7 *NÎLÍKNÍ-ÖK,ÉÐK®JXX´¸$±¤´¨Ä1Óµ±

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have Memcached compression turned on.  This may just be a compressed version of your data.

Comment: Does this compression start at a certain length? Because I just tried removing the colon and slashes from the string, and that didn't work, and then I made the string a little shorter again and then it worked.

Comment: I guess it does... Anyways, how do I get rid of it in php? The C# client I'm using (or going to use), Enyim, doesn't seem to support compressing... I can't find an option in the php-memcached.cnf file.

Comment: It depends on which extension you're using.  For instance, for Memcached, use Memcached::setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, false)